# How to get the content of a ViewResult in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-word, viewresult

I have a view that is rendered with ContentType of "application/msword". For users this appears as download file. Now, I would like to save this document server side. How could get I access the rendered document server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    var viewContext =
        new ViewContext(
            filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext,
            vResult.View,
            vResult.ViewData,
            vResult.TempData,
            writer);

    vResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server you could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to fire an HTTP request to the url and [download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) the file or [download it in memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) as a byte array.